# Git file missing from workspace

Tags: git

When I do a `git status`, part of the output is the following:

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

both modified:   Logging/src/logutils/mplogctl.py
```

The problem is that `mplogctl.py` has disappeared from the current branch and I can find no way to fix the workspace so that I can continue to use the repository.

Comment: Can you describe how you got here? Did you do `git pull` or an explicit `git merge <branch>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `git checkout -m Logging/src/logutils/mplogctl.py` to copy it from the index to your working directory. Make sure to resolve the conflicts before adding and committing it!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work and I get the following error:  (Sabia) jonathan@Aristotle:~/Dropbox/Git Repositories/Sabia$ git checkout Logging/src/logutils/mplogctl.py
error: path 'Logging/src/logutils/mplogctl.py' is unmerged

Comment: @Jonathan - sorry about that; you need to use the `-m` option. I have updated my answer.